# How to export textures with JarSplice?

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, jarsplice

I have another game that uses rectangles instead of textures which works fine. When I run it I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Owner>cd desktop

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop>java -jar FLIPPERFLAP1.0.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\FlubberFlap.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
        at FSMain.MainFS.main(MainFS.java:68)

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop>
```

In line 68 where I load the texture, I do this :

```
wood = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/SuperGuy.png")));
```

It works when I use the IDE (eclipse) but not after exported. The images are in a source folder called res. When I use JarSplice do I have to export the textures in natives or jars?

Comment: Hello Mr.CodeIt! I've posted an answer in JGO. I'm posting it here too now.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using FileInputStream to load resources. You should use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream or similar. See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50967/2158

Answer (score -1):

First step is make sure you have the resources bundled with the JAR you create. Try to move the `res/` folder inside the `src/` folder. And export the jar like this.

[image]

And create the fat jar as you did. This gets rid of the Eclipse's JAR in JAR loader.

Comment: Woah your the same one on JGO, but do I keep the res/ folder as a source folder or regular folder? Source folders wont go in the src/

Comment: You should keep it as a package. Just create a package with `res` as name and drag the files inside your res folder into it.

Comment: After I export like you said, where do I get my natives from in jarSPlice? Where I downloaded it? Or do I just put the jar in?

Comment: You add the jars `lwjgl.jar` `lwjgl-util.jar` `slick-util.jar` and jars of any other libraries you are using. Then add the natives that you have from the LWJGL download.

Comment: Where do I put my textures?

Comment: In the `res/` package.

Comment: I realized my problem, I thought you could only load textures in lwjgl. If I have a method in a player class called draw with graphics g, and it draws an image to the screen, would I call this instead of image.bind() ?

Comment: @downvoter Could you please say why?